# Temp table in postgresql is getting dropped at the end of the session. How to solve it?

Tags: postgresql, temp-tables, global-temp-tables

At the end of the current session the table is getting dropped, and all the values is lost. What can I do to solve this issue?

Comment: [`Temp table`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/static/sql-createtable.html)- "Temporary tables **are automatically dropped at the end of a session**, or optionally at the end of the current transaction"

Comment: If you really have "Temp table" then this behavior is "by design" - see here - https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createtable.html - " TEMPORARY or TEMP
If specified, the table is created as a temporary table. Temporary tables are automatically dropped at the end of a session, or optionally at the end of the current transaction (see ON COMMIT below). Existing permanent tables with the same name are not visible to the current session while the temporary table exists, unless they are referenced with schema-qualified names. Any indexes are automatically dropped too..."

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? To me this behaviour is pretty desirable for a temporary table...

Comment: @madflow: that depends on the viewpoint ;) In Oracle for example a temporary table is a persisted object that is created **once** and contains sessions specific data. But the table definition itself is never discarded automatically. I _think_ this is was Tijo expects in Postgres as well.

Answer (score 1):

Postgresql has not global temp tables. There is not any clean solution.